# Removing all componentWillMount from my project, what is the replacement if my child components depend on an api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Hopefully not an xy issue, react deprecated some lifecycle methods, we were using component will mount to make api calls in one of our parent components as the children content depends on what is returned from this api call.

At the time we couldn’t use componentDidMount for the calls since child component lifecycle methods trigger before the parent’s componentDidMount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the API call into `componentDidMount` will work if you use conditional rendering to only render the child component(s) once the API response comes back and updates state. Something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      parent component stuff
      { this.state.apiResults ? <Child apiResults={this.state.apiResults} /> : null }
    </div>
  );
}
```

where the `fetch` result updates `apiResults` in state.

Comment: after looking around, this seems to be the most 'react' way to solve this issue, two of the points from the other answer would also work.

using UNSAFE_componentWillMount or useEffect.

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

- Switch `componentWillMount` to `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`. This is a short-term fix and will not work from React 17, so not recommended.
- Move your API code to the constructor of the component if it's a class component.
- Convert your component to a functional component and move it inside `useEffect`. This is recommended:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // API code
}, []);
```